# every time i compile exe c++ program its detected as a virus

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2019, virus

example of said program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("aa");
    return 0;
}
```

i put this program in virustotal and here is its output:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/8ba14bd65c6a83e6b776359ebdefad41e039ee0091e37300a7b463f497277d52/detection

I'm using visual studio with visual c++ compiler. this problem occurs EVEN after i freshly reinstalled windows (i thought i have some kind of virus that injects its code into my program, so i thought reinstalling windows would help). even stranger is that windows defender doesn't detect any issues with that same program... is that normal problem with visual c++ compiler? or i might have some kind of virus, even after reinstalling windows?

Comment: There might be some kind of signature match. Do other programs raise the same flag?

Comment: yea.. like i said every program, no mater what i write, after i compile it to exe, its detected as a virus... its scary ngl

Comment: False positive - it's a bug in virustotal - it's being too cautious. Report to them. FWIW, I have something similar going on with a different product and a different compiler. For me, it does not happen with more complex (realistic) programs.

Comment: I'd double check with something other than VirusTotal because it could be completely out to lunch.

Comment: also when i try to upload executable it to google drive, or send it to gmail it also detects a virus.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xcIXcpP

Comment: maybe google virus detection also is too cautious? im confused. are your executables also have a same problem with google?

Comment: if it was 1 virus scanner I'd say its definitely a false positive, the fact its detected by a few is a little suspicious. When you reinstalled windows did you keep any files? where did you get your visual studio installer from? Have you tried testing a release build rather than a debug build?

Comment: i fully reinstalled windows and downloaded visual studio community edition from official microsoft webside. i just tried the release build and the same problem occurs: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/ef0e7bbc5c20c69d19001e649723bebec9a7c5d2ce7bb558cb206bd6e26282da/detection

same with google virus detection...

Comment: acually google drive seems ok with release build, but for some reason gmail and virustotal still detects virus... im even more confused

Comment: This is what we realized in daily business: The shorter the (test) program the more suspicious it appears to the virus checker... (The other suspicious thing seems to be the existence of literal HTML code in a program. I once wrote a conversion tool for HTML entities <-> XML entities. That caused me permanent trouble as well until I white-listed it...)

Comment: i tried to test my game program (~1000-2000 lines of code). still same shtuff

Comment: i should probably decompile my code to see whats wrong with it. ill probably get nowhere but its still worth the try.

Comment: i couldnt find this website sorry. i only know virustotal.

Comment: this virustotal website is a complete disaster for anything compiled with visual studio, there is literally nothing I can compile that will pass all of the tests